# Pyinstaller with tkinter app dont execute

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have a tkinter app who is running fine im trying to create a executable version of it , using pyinstaller the build process is finished without errors but when i run the exe file nothing happen, i get a spinner of loading on the mouse and thats it.

Spec file

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['main.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\WallaceSilva\\Desktop\\pyinstaller'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='setup',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               upx_exclude=[],
               name='setup')
```